# Can we give height in % in jQuery?{Colsed}

Tags: jquery, css

Can we give height in % in jQuery:

```
jQuery("#amazingslider-1").amazingslider({

        jsfolder:jsFolder,

        width:1024,
        height:500,

        skinsfoldername:"",

        loadimageondemand:false,

        isresponsive:true,

        autoplayvideo:false,
```

How can we give height in percent (%)?

Comment: use `addClass` to a add a class which has width and height in percentages.

Comment: You are using plugin I guess so it depends on that.

Comment: @Vinita : just for your FYI **accepting answers is a good gesture if it helped....i see in your questions history that, you just ask questions and never accept any answers, even though it is correct....this way, sooner or later, people would stop answering ur queries....!!** Read this if u get time : http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, just wrap in quotation marks:

```
width:"100%",
height:"50%"
```

EDIT:

see the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/PUbbK/)

Comment: it works. make sure the parent element has width set because 50% is supposed to be 50% of something, if parent element has no size, then 50% of no thing is still nothing. i updated my answer

Comment: it sure works mate...+1, maintaining equilibrium!! :)

Comment: @Banana : she has issues accepting answer ( *i hate such OP's literally* ) ....but u have my upvote...cheers!! :D

Comment: its alright mate, thanks for the equilibrium :p cheers

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
  jQuery("#amazingslider-1").css('width','100%') 
  jQuery("#amazingslider-1").css('height','100%')
```

OR

```
  jQuery("#amazingslider-1").width('100%').height('100%');
```